# DISM to Capture Entire Disk As-Is

Tags: backup, disk-image, dism, wim

In short: Is it possible to leverage dism to capture an image of an entire disk as-is, akin to taking an image with Ghost, GParted, PartedMagic, CloneZilla etc.?

I've got a shiny new machine and before I tear into it, I'd like an image of the disk to get back to this point today.  We use MDT and are in the process of standing up SCCM so I have some exposure to dism.

I know I can use dism to create WIMs of volumes with the caveat that they have to have letters assigned, right?  What about entire disks as-is?

This machine has:

- 1 disk

  - 5 partitions:

    - Recovery 1000MB
    - System 260MB
    - Reserved 128MB
    - Primary 462GB
    - Recovery 12GB
  - 5 volumes:

    - Vol 0: E DVD
    - Vol 1: C Windows OS
    - Vol 2:   WINRE_DRV Hidden
    - Vol 3:   SYSTEM_DRV Hidden
    - Vol 4:   Lenovo_Recovery Hidden
    - Vol 5: D USB Boot Media

The only way I can think of to capture all this is to

- Assign letters to the hidden volumes via diskpart (sel vol n > assign > repeat > exit) resulting in:

  - Vol 1: C Windows OS
  - Vol 2: F WINRE_DRV
  - Vol 3: G SYSTEM_DRV
  - Vol 4: H Lenovo_Recovery
- Create the initial wim:

  - dism /capture-image /imagefile:\path\to\backup.wim /capturedir:c: /name:C-WinOS
- Append other volumes to the initial wim:

  - dism /append-image /imagefile:\path\to\backup.wim /capturedir:F: /name:F-WINRE_DRV
  - dism /append-image /imagefile:\path\to\backup.wim /capturedir:G: /name:G-SYSTEM_DRV
  - dism /append-image /imagefile:\path\to\backup.wim /capturedir:H: /name:H-Lenovo_Reco

Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: Your method is the way.  You image each partition into its own file.  You then create the partitions and apply the image to the partition.  I just did use this exact approach.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you want to use DISM? I think you’re terribly overcomplicating things. Just grab a LZO-compressed full disk image.

Comment: @DanielB: No 'special reason' per-se but...
(a) Since I'm not the only one managing images, I find its easier for others if I keep things consistent.  Some folks here may not know how to access another format.
(b) I wanted to leverage existing technology & infrastructure to capture an image.  I have a working 'capture-only' task sequence, but it wasn't getting everything which is what made me dive deeper into this.
(c) I've also never thought of or tried creating an LZO-compressed disk image.  Got any recommendations?

Thanks again!

Comment: What you want to achieve here is quite different from what DISM is aimed at. You’re trying to capture the disk state, 1:1. The way to go for that is, for course, a full image. It’ll also include the partition table and any boot code. Whether you compress it or not is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Phylum - How did this work out for you? I might try to do the same for a machine.

Comment: @Ramhound - When would you do this WIM (File based Image) via DISM versus VHD (Sectory based Image) via a Disk2VHD / Paragon HDM style S/w?

Comment: @AlexS - The DISM process is faster.  I can create a .wim image of one partition and then apply it to a different partition all using a single PowerShell script.

Comment: @Ramhound - Nice. Care to share some sample scripts :) ?

Comment: @AlexS - I have numerous scripts. They are just not my scripts to just hand out, and also, outside of the scope of this question.  They are also isolated on a secured system, so even I wanted to share them (I do not), I don't have the means to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound - Fair enough - Could you point me to similar samples/ examples out there? Would you on this Q or if I post a question for that?

Comment: hey @AlexS - By the time I had posted to SU, I had already executed and it worked well.  Fortunately, I didn't need to go back to that configuration so I ultimately destroyed the WIM.  If you're familiar with PowerShell, and on a recent version, like 5 - check $PSVersionTable.PSVersion - then it's worth looking into if you have an unusual layout.  When I build machines from scratch, I don't create a disk layout like this; usually its manufacturers like Dell, Lenovo & HP that do things like this and this was a one-off. (and thank goodness for that!)

Answer (score 6):

You can now do it easily with the new "[Windows Full Flash Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-windows-using-full-flash-update--ffu)", integrated in DISM starting from Windows 10 v1709

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but I'll explore this further.  On the surface this looks exactly like what I needed, albeit 3 years ago. ;)  I really do appreciate this golden nugget!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but not necessarily easy. You could use [/Append-Image](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824916) to capture all partitions to one WIM file and then deploy each partition with DISM from that WIM file on the other side. It still isn’t a sector-based image or a disk level image, DISM is a volume imaging tool that uses WIM file-based imaging.

Another alternative is that you could [Disk2VHD](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/ee656415) the reference system and then use [Boot to VHD](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh825691) to boot the deployed systems.

Comment: I missed that you were already using /Append-Image. You should also check out the official guidance on this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh825041